# Plugin Wordpress hacer uso de add_action, is_plugin_active, get_option

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Desde wordpress me indican lo siguiente sobre el desarrollo de un plugin:

> ### Calling core loading files directly
>
> Including wp-config.php, wp-blog-header.php, wp-load.php, or pretty
>   much any other WordPress core file that you have to call directly via
>   an include is not permitted.
>
> These calls are prone to failure as not all WordPress installs have
>   the exact same file structure. In addition it opens your plugin to
>   security issues, as WordPress can be easily tricked into running code
>   in an unauthenticated manner.
>
> Your code should always exist in functions and be called by action
>   hooks. This is true even if you need code to exist outside of
>   WordPress. Code should only be accessible to people who are logged in
>   and authorized, if it needs that kind of access. Your plugin's pages
>   should be called via the dashboard like all the other settings panels,
>   and in that way, they'll always have access to WordPress functions.
>
> - https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/

En mi caso hago uso de las siguientes funciones propias de wordpress:

- add_action
- get_option
- is_plugin_active
- get_current_user_id
- $webhook = new \WC_Webhook();
- add_filter

En las clases donde se hacía uso de alguna de estas funciones se hacía lo siguiente:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../../../../../wp-load.php';
```

Al eliminar dicho requiere, el plugin ha dejado de iniciarse. Wordpress tiene el modo debug activo pero el log está vacío. Tanto el propio de WP como el de PHP

**EDITO:**
Parece que puede ser el uso de defined('ABSPATH') || exit;

¿Como puedo hacer uso de esta opción para evitar que se acceda a mis ficheros directamente desde fuera del módulo?

Comment: Qué funciones necesitas utilizar? En realidad si el plugin está corriendo en una instalación de WP (no tiene sentido llamarlo plugin si no es así), puede que muchas funciones que estás requiriendo ya están en memoria, y por tanto no necesitas hacer esos require de archivos a mano.

Comment: Hay que hacer uso de las rutas de wordpress y las query vars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución para poder acceder a dichos ficheros mediante URL es generar rutas de wordpress y hacer uso de las query-vars.

**EDITO:**

Fue haciendo uso de esto https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8229/passing-and-retrieving-query-vars-in-wordpress

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar un ejemplo de esto? Te sugerimos revisar [answer] para que aportes más información que sea de beneficio a la comunidad que tengan la misma pregunta.

Comment: Cierto, disculpa. Ya he editado la entrada con esto https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8229/passing-and-retrieving-query-vars-in-wordpress